# how to update a list content in lwuit at runtime

Tags: list, java-me, lwuit

I have designed a lwuit form with a textfield and a list bottom of it. Now, I want following functionality:

every time user changes a textfield content, list should be refreshed (like autocomlplete feature)
but I don't know how to refresh a list?
for creating a list I have used following code:

```
choicelists = createList(urbanplacechoiceGroup, List.VERTICAL, new PlaceRenderer());
```

and for listening to texhfield changes:

```
Urbanareas_textpublic.addDataChangeListener(new DataChangedListener() {

        public void dataChanged(int type, int index) {
            System.out.println("text content: " + Urbanareas_textpublic.getText());
            populateurbanplacechoiceGroup();
         }
    });
```

urbanplacechoiceGroup is used to populate urbanplacechoiceGroup which its content used for choicelists.

I found this function and it does updating a list:

choicelists.setRenderer(new PlaceRenderer());

is it a standard way to updating list?
what happened to PlaceRenderer objects which was created before?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use in list that work with [ListCellRenderer](http://lwuit.blogspot.co.il/2008/07/lwuit-list-renderer-by-chen-fishbein.html).

This is dinamic list that use to dispalying data list.In addtional this list save up use in memory ,because he don't create a list but use data only to display.

Comment: my PlaceRendere implemented ListCellRendere! I dont know how to update it? for example after I have updated urbanplacechoicegroup which contains my data, how could I refresh ListCellRenderer to show the changes?

Comment: i found setRenderer(...) function as I added to my question. is it a standard way?

Comment: Yes, when you want update your list. we need call this function

Answer (score 1):

See this post http://codenameone.blogspot.com/2008/06/lightweight-text-input-in-lwuit.html

It covers filtering a list dynamically, basically what you are looking for is a list model which abstracts the data of the list.